# What is the maximum number of toads you can get in Super Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

I would like to know the maximum number of toads you can get from toad rally in Super Mario Run. Does the game even have an ending, after you collect all of the collectibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this website: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/195777-super-mario-run/74774589

The max number of Toads is capped at 9999. On another note, the maximum number of Toad Rally Tickets is capped at 99.

Answer (score 0):

As of an update in April 2017, you can now have up to 99,999 toads. There are new buildings that take advantage of the increased limit- for example, the most expensive building, Peach's Tent, requires 50,000 toads of any color to unlock.